# How to print a String after another String?

Tags: php, string

Hi How can i print an String after another String?
This is my file for reading:

members.txt

```
Name: john
Family: Bell

Name: max
Family: King
```

i want Only Print string after "Name: "
What should i do?
i mean Name: john is one string and want to print string after "Name: "

Comment: What have you tried?  From the looks of it, nothing.  Have a look at the problem.  What can you see?  Obviously you need to read those lines in to a string.  What functions might you use to separate `name` and `John`?  What would you do after?  At least *try*.

Comment: i only want to "echo" the string after "Name: " and "Family: " can u help me?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: +1 to Moo-Juice. Try yourself before asking peple here to do it for you.. Tons of guides around telling how to both read from txt-files and parse strings to get only the part you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (file('members.txt') as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'Name:') !== FALSE) {
        echo trim(substr($line, 6))."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually understanding the question and trying to answer it! However, from the manual for strstr "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead."

Comment: i mean Name: john is one string and want to print string after "Name: "

Comment: That's what this code should do, but there's another typo. `!= FALSE` should be `!== FALSE`. Otherwise good code. Better than my (too complex) attempt, which I will not post now ofcourse. :)

Comment: Also, fread() isn't for reading line-by-line; I think you mean file(), which reads lines into an array